# Copy a row from one sheet to another sheet if the row contains a certain value

Tags: vba, copy, row, paste

This shouldn't be complicated code, but I am new to Excel VBA. I've tried many different methods resulting in bugs, infinite loops, and wrong selections.

I need to go row by row through "Sheet1" selecting one row at a time, check if the value in Column J is correct (value = 131125), if it is then copy - paste the row to "Sheet2" (into the same row as it was in Sheet1).

Help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")
    If Cell.Value = "131125" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: NP. Tag the answer if you find it useful ;-)

Comment: @MieerDarwesh - Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803155/any-way-to-use-vba-on-google-spreadsheet) SO question.