# excel copy rows which have specific word in them to another sheet in the same order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called "Paste Availability Data Here" which has a number in column A, dates and times in column C and D and a summary in column E. Column B either has the word "OK" or "ERROR" in it. What i want to do is copy all rows that only have the word "ERROR" in column B to a new sheet called "Availability".

The data starts on Row 3 and has the potential to have at least 700 rows of data.

I need a Macro that automatically copies the data to sheet "Availability" when the data is pasted into "Paste Availability Data Here" each month.

I have tried to do it with IF functions but it does not want to work.

```
Sub Test() 
  For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("B:B") 
    If Cell.Value = "ERROR" Then 
      matchRow = Cell.Row 
      Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select 
      Selection.Copy 
      Sheets("Availability").Select 
      ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select 
      ActiveSheet.Paste 
      Sheets("Paste Availability Data Here").Select 
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Image attached of the worksheet

Many thanks

Comment: I actually am doing something similar to this, did you want to accomplish this with a button of some sort or an automatic process?

Comment: also i need it to be an automatic process

Comment: The one i have kinda posted above works but it leaves blanks on the new sheet. I want all populated rows to be consecutive with no blank rows where the rows with OK in them were

Comment: @CHale StackOverflow is not a place to request for codes. Automation process is already been answered in other questions. Conditional copying also has answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy a row from one sheet to another sheet if the row contains a certain value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269725/copy-a-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-sheet-if-the-row-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: @Masoud, unfortunately as described above this does not remove blank rows on the sheet copied to. I have tried to use paste special but also this errors when activated

Comment: @CHale See my answer you just need to add another index for rows in the second sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job but you need change the indices and names for your particular problem. Post another question for automation (however it has already been answered [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time.htm)).

```
Dim wsh1 As Worksheet
Dim wsh2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Sub Conditional_Copy()

Set wsh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

i = 1
j = 1

Do While wsh1.Cells(i, 2) <> ""

    If wsh1.Cells(i, 2) = "ERROR" Then

        wsh1.Rows(i).Copy wsh2.Rows(j)

        j = j + 1

    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```