# Copying a Row from a Table using a cell that contains a VLOOKUP equation

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty unfamiliar with VBA, and I am stuck with this portion of my code. I have a cell with a vlookup equation in it I'd like to use as a parameter to find a value in a table on a different sheet and copy the entire row over to a different sheet. I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269725/copy-a-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-sheet-if-the-row-contains-a-certain-value) in the past to copy data over based on a single parameter, but I think the problem I'm running into is that the cell I'm trying to reference contains a vlookup equation in it.

```
Sub Test()
For Each cell In Sheets(RawDataLoader).Range("E:E")
If cell.Value = "B8" Then
    matchRow = cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("RawDataLoader").Select
End If
Next
End Sub
```

RawDataLoader is the sheet with my table

Dashboard is the sheet where I want the cells to go

B8 is the cell on the sheet Dashboard I want to use as the value the table looks up.

The range with the values I want it to search through is E:E and on the RawDataLoader sheet.

I know that the cell.value portion of my code is incorrect, I just do not know how to reference a cell value, so I put the cell I wanted to reference.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to find each cell in column E that contains a value equal to whatever is in range B8 and then copy all the matching rows, or...?
It's not completely clear to me.

Comment: Change `If cell.Value = "B8" Then` to `If cell.Value = range("B8").Value Then` for starters..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B8").value` instead of `"B8"`. You can also simplify your code; avoid using `Select` and loop only on the used range instead of the full column.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim cell as Range
  For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("RawDataLoader").UsedRange, Sheets("RawDataLoader").Range("E:E"))
    If cell.Value = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B8").value Then
      cell.EntireRow.copy Sheets("Dashboard").Rows(cell.Row)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it gave me a runtime error, "Script out of range"

Comment: @Lampoa There was missing double-quotes around `RawDataLoader`. Try again the edited code. btw this would've been easier to catch had you used `Option Explicit`, which is always recommended.